# ESXi LACP with DELL PowerConnect

Tags: vmware-esxi, load-balancing, lacp, dell-powerconnect

I am using ESXi 6.7 U3 (free version) on a ProLiant SE326M1 R2 (basically a DL180 G6 equivalent). I do know, it's old - but it does its job and ESXi has not complained yet.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

- Connect both RJ45 GBE NICs of the Server to my DELL PowerConnect 6248 switch
- Set up a LACP LAG between ESXi virtual switch
- Configure the LAG as VLAN trunk for two separate VLANs (Management and Server network)

What I did so far:

- Set up LACP port channel on the DELL switch, configured its switchport mode to trunk and added both allowed VLANs
- Enabled VLAN architecture awareness on ESXi, set management interface to MGMT VLAN number

But if I check the portchannel status in my pyhsical switch CLI, it shows both links as inactive. The hashing algorithm is set to 3 - Source IP on the DELL switch and to "IP Route Hash" on ESXi.
I've already tried setting the DELL's hash mode to 6 - Source/Destination IP, but it does not work either.

Am I missing something? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, LACP is only supported by vDS's not vSS's, vDS's are created and managed by vCenter, therefore you cannot have LACP without vCenter and a paid licence, not free.

Comment: I hate vmware... xD But thank you for clarification, Chopper

Comment: They're a business, they're trying to make money, they give away 80% of their core product for free, they want you to pay for the higher-functionality options that cost them money to develop is all.

Comment: Yeah, of course, they need to pay there devs. Was more meant to be a sarcastic comment from a student running servers on tight budget ^^